# Massively stuck wanting my drop down selection bring up 1 of the 4 classes stats?

Tags: python, tkinter

What I am struggling with is after clicking my drop down menu to select a player class I would like the said class stats to appear on the screen. Preferably to the left middle.

I'm doing a project for my college course where I need to create a game UI. The most part has been done even impressed myself by adding background music.
I just cant seem to get anything to work. I have tried the when this button is clicked get this but it either throws an error message or it runs and no errors but doesn't do as intended probably because the code I have tried is almost there but its waiting for some other command. The attributes will need to have a plus and minus button and the values can be changed this part of coding I have to hand ready to be implemented its just getting this phase done first. I kind of have done this backwards I know but some of the coding has come quicker to me than other parts.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: Now I know the story, but to help you I need to know your code. Preferably a [mre], cause I don't like to search a lot of code for a minor change. You might take the [tour] or look into [ask], because at this point it is no way solving your issue. Please [edit] your code in order to get help, before your question gets closed.

Comment: def Warrior():
    ["STATS",
     "Strength 5",
     "Dexterity 4",
     "Charisma, 2",
     "Intelligence 2",
     "ARMOUR TYPE: Heavy",
     "CLASS SKILL: 2 Handed Weapons"

Comment: sorry didnt mean to click, that is one of the classes and this the code before it clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set("Select Charatcer") 

drop = OptionMenu (gui, clicked, "Warrior", "Ranger", "Thief", "Mage")
my_canvas.create_window(275, 10, window=drop, anchor="nw")
drop.config(width =20, height=3, font=("Old English Text MT", 15))

Comment: from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog, messagebox
import os This is what I have at the start, the os was so that I could create a reset button so the gui quit and instantly reloads fresh

Comment: Don't post code in comment.  Post the code in the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How do I post the code in the question it wont allow me to edit the post?